# Abort DoJo XHR-Request

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest, abort

I'm using the [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html) module for HTTP Requests.
Is it possible to abort the active request as it is possible with a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29)?

Thank you in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise returned by `dojo/request/xhr` has a cancel method (like normal promises), which aborts the HTTP request.

```
var request = xhr("foo/bar").then(someHandler, someErrorHandler);
...
if(!request.isResolved()) {
    request.cancel(); // aborts request and triggers the error handler
}
```

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/QgWNA/

Comment: Your solution works. But using a XMLHttpRequest.abort() stops also the according server process. The request.cancel() doesn't. Is it possible to stop the server process additionally?

Comment: if the server receives the request, it can not be cancelled