# Abort HTTP-Request Server process

Tags: ajax, dojo, abort, http-request

As shown in [Abort DoJo XHR-Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046007/abort-dojo-xhr-request) it is possible to cancel a (dojo/request/xhr) http request on the Client.
The problem is, that the according server process (initiated by the request) is still running.

If we use a XMLHttpRequest-Object, calling abort() on it would stop the server process.

So the question is: Is it possible to achive this with dojo? Or is it possible to get access to the internal XMLHttpRequest-Object (used by dojo/request/xhr) to call abort() on it?

Comment: `dojo/request/xhr` calls `abort` on the underlying xhr object when you cancel, so it's not clear why it should behave any differently than calling `xhr.abort` directly; see [here](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.9.3/request/xhr.js#L70) and [here](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.9.3/request/xhr.js#L116).  Are you testing with the same service in both cases?

Comment: Ah, thanks for this information. I must review...

Comment: I call cancel(). Then the error handler of the request is called. This is good. But the Server process (a long poll) is still running (I can see it in my logfile). Maybe it could be a solution if the server process could detect the cancelation. In this case it could terminate itself!?

Comment: Yes, you might need to do something on the server end to abort a process when the connection aborts.  Check your net tab in firebug / developer tools to make sure the request shows up as canceled once `cancel` is called; beyond that there's no more you can do client-side.

Comment: My mistake was, that in my obsolet version the page has been reloaded on each user action. So my "abort" on the server seems to work. But with AJAX there is another environment. Sorry.